Remove Quotes When Copying Multiple Cells From Excel
What I am trying to do, is select multiple cells from an Excel file and paste the results in another program (for now lets say sticky notes or note pad). I plan on doing this with a VBA macro attached to a form control button. So clicking the button would select and copy, for example, cells b13:b29. That data could then be pasted into the target text editor. The cells being copied contain multiple types of data (plain text, numbers wrapped in the dollar() function, and concat() strings that include line breaks. I have the select/copy part of the macro worked out.
The issue is, when I copy a cell that has a line break in it, the resultant paste contains starting and ending quotes, like this:
"Line number one
Line number two"
I need those quotes to vacate my screen.
From my understanding, there is a way to remove those quotes using VBA as well.
NOW, here's the other parameter: This will be used by several other of my colleagues who are not very tech savvy. So the solution cannot include the need to install or reference the Microsoft Forms 2.0 library (or any additional back end installation.)
We are using Microsoft 365 on Windows 10 or 11 (some people are on 10, some on 11)
I have tried using multiple posted VBA solutions, but all included the need to install the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library. When I try to run their code, I get an error. The solution needs to NOT include using the MS Forms 2.0 Library (or anything that isnt native to excel 365 that would need to be installed/set up)

It would be useful to see the relevant parts of your code. Does it actually do a copy/paste or to you put the content of the cells in a string which you then write in Sticky Notes/Notepad/whatever? If the former, you could maybe do a search and replace in the target software? If the latter you could do the search and replace on the string.

The VBA that Im using for the copy selection is as follows:
Sub COPYSUPPDOC()
'
' COPYSUPPDOC Macro
'
'
Sheets("CALC SHEET").Select
Range("L5:L26").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Supplements").Select
Range("F4").Select
End Sub
Its not super complex, but has worked so far. Will this integrate with what is being presented?

And no, Im not having thet VBA do the copy and paste, just the copy to the clipboard

Only reliable piece of code that I found that writes into the Clipboard is using the Microsoft HTML Object Library, as described in this answer
I ended up with the following routine
Public Sub PutTextToClipboard(txt As Variant)
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        With .parentWindow.clipboardData
            .SetData "text", txt
        End With
    End With
End Sub

(Tested on W11/64 with Office 365 and on W10/32 with Office 2016)
Now all you have to do is to create a string from your (selected) cells. Have a look to the following function. You can change how the cells are separated, default is to have a line break for every cell:
Public Function CellsToString(r As Range, _
                              Optional colSeparator As String = vbCrLf, _
                              Optional rowSeparator As String = vbCrLf)
    Dim s As String, row As Long, col As Long
    
    For row = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        s = s & IIf(row > 1, rowSeparator, "")
        For col = 1 To r.Columns.Count
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim cellValue As String
            cellValue = "???"
            cellValue = CStr(r.Cells(row, col))
            On Error GoTo 0
            s = s & IIf(col > 1, colSeparator, "") & cellValue
        Next
    Next
    CellsToString = s
End Function

And the code of the button
Sub Button1_Click() 
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a Range first"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    PutTextToClipboard CellsToString(Selection, " : ")
    MsgBox Selection.Count & " cells written to clipboard"
End Sub

Update If you know which range you want to copy, use something like this:
Sub COPYSUPPDOC() 
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("L5:L26")
    PutTextToClipboard CellsToString(r, " : ")
    MsgBox Selection.Count & " cells written to clipboard"
End Sub


The VBA that Im using for the copy selection is as follows:
Sub COPYSUPPDOC()
'
' COPYSUPPDOC Macro
'
'
Sheets("CALC SHEET").Select
Range("L5:L26").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Supplements").Select
Range("F4").Select
End Sub
Its not super complex, but has worked so far. Will this integrate with what is being presented?

Your code uses Excel to Copy the data into the Clipboard. My code uses VBA. When you use Excel, you need to live with what Excel copies. When you use VBA, you are free to write whatever you want. I have misread your question, I thought you want to copy the current Selection - but it's really easy to adapt the code, I update my answer. That said: You don't need to use Select in VBA to work on a Range.

Btw: Don't put code into comments, it's getting unreadable. You can always edit your question and put the code there.
